# rails 3 and acts-as-readable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does the acts-as-readable plugin work for rails 3? The instructions at https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-readable results in `Plugin not found: ["http://svn.intridea.com/svn/public/acts_as_readable"]`

Downloading the source from github and sticking it in vendor/plugin doesn't seem to work, I get: `Could not find generator acts_as_readable_migration`.

I am doing something wrong or should I look elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forked the plugin to my GitHub account and updated its generators to work with Rails 3, which can be found at https://github.com/tjackiw/acts-as-readable.

After you install it

`rails plugin install git://github.com/tjackiw/acts-as-readable.git`

then you can do

`rails generate acts_as_readable_migration`

Have fun!

Comment: Installing the plugin results in no messages at all and the plugin was not installed in /vendor/plugin, or anywhere else from what I can tell. Running generator results in could not find generator message.

Comment: I ran the plugin install with the verbose flag and got this: rails: version unknown

Comment: What rails/ruby version are you using? My setup is Rails 3.0.9 and Ruby 1.9.2 and it installed just fine under vendor/plugins and I was able to run the generator.

Comment: I used this downtime as an excuse to update ruby to the latest 1.9.2 build and tried again and the plugin did actually install this time. It still is not able to find to find the generator.

Comment: Alright! I was able to replicate the "no generator error" by creating a new rails app and testing it that way. I've fixed the problem and if you do a fresh install of the plugin it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I did have to create a Reading model class, but seems to work well. Thank you very much, your work is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try `script/rails plugin install git://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-readable.git` to install it from that git repo.

Looks like it will install, but uncertain if it "works" given it hasn't been updated since 2008

Comment: I tried that and got no error message but it isn't in the plugin folder. I tried it again and got a message saying it was already installed. Am I missing something about how plugins work?

Comment: No, I think it installed. When I try it (after I added an actual User model) I the same error message you did - "Could not find generator acts_as_readable_migration". So, looks like the plugin needs to be updated for Rails 3.